# Converting non-ascii characters and write them in a json file in python

Tags: python, json, encoding, ascii

I downloaded data from facebook that looks like this:

```
data = 
    [
            {
                "content": "Hi",
                "sender_name": "J\u00c3\u00a9r\u00c3\u00a9my",
                "timestamp_ms": 1575674161100,
                "type": "Generic"
            },
            {
                "content": "Yeah",
                "sender_name": "Christo",
                "timestamp_ms": 1575674143398,
                "type": "Generic"
            },
            {
                "content": "Hello",
                "sender_name": "William",
                "timestamp_ms": 1575674130441,
                "type": "Generic"
            },
            {
                "content": "Bruh",
                "sender_name": "William",
                "timestamp_ms": 1575674121964,
                "type": "Generic"
            }
        ]
```

My goal is to take generate a json file containing all messages but without the unicode escape. For exemple, I'd like `J\u00c3\u00a9r\u00c3\u00a9my` to show as `Jérémy`. I've tried several things like reading the file line by line doing this:

```
with open(src_filename, 'r') as src_file:
    with open(dst_filename, 'w') as dst_file:
        for line in src_file:
            dst_file.write(line.encode('latin_1').decode('utf-8'))
```

It works in the terminal.

```
u1 = "J\u00c3\u00a9r\u00c3\u00a9my"
print(u1.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8'))
```

It shows `Jérémy` in the terminal, but not in my file.

I also tried the json dumps method

```
with open("filename", "w") as json_file:
    json_string = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8').decode('utf8')
    json.dump(json_string, json_file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

but it doesn't recognize some characters: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x83' in position 276: character maps to <undefined>` (Note that my actual data is a lot more messages and mostly in French)

How can I write my data in a json file while showing special french characters such as "é", "à", "è" or other non-ascii characters like "%"?

Answer (score 1):

played around with it for a while until I got it:

```
with open('filename.json', 'w') as fp:
    json_string = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
    fp.write(json_string)
```

your problem came from trying to `json.dump` again, while `json_string` can just be written to the file

Comment: Thanks for your response, you led me to the right answer. Because the content is already a string, json.dumps() changes "\u00c3" to "\\u00c3" and I can't decode it. I iterated over all my messages and changed the encode for the value itself.

```
for msg in json_data:
if 'sender_name' in msg.keys():
                msg['sender_name'] = msg['sender_name'].encode('latin1').decode('utf-8', errors="replace")
```